# How are internal components of Android tested before releasing?

Tags: security, stock-android, linux, rom

How are the internal components of Android such as Zygote and Binder tested before being released?

I tried looking around for answers to this but most resources (blog posts and research papers) I could find dealt mostly with Android application testing and/or verification techniques for Android applications and not the system itself.

A (somewhat) related official information I found was [Android Compatibility Test Suite(CTS)](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/). I suppose this is aimed at hardware vendors who customize AOSP code for their devices. CTS performs high level compatibility checks from user applications only but not all code of internal components is tested.

If there are no publicly known techniques currently being used in Android, are there any known techniques proposed for other operating systems which would be applicable for Android?

I am working on replacing some components of Android entirely and looking for efficient ways to test them (correctness, compatibility, security and more perhaps).

Edit: It is sufficient for me to know how internal components of Android such as Zygote and Binder are tested when changes are made to them. Since they are internal components, the testing could be very likely automated. Also, I am hoping to replacing these components with functionally equivalent code so these tests will help establish that no critical functionality has been affected.

Comment: Have you forgotten about the Developer Previews Google releases for testing to developers before every major Android version upgrade? What about those?

Comment: Also, this post about compiler reliability might give you an idea: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/51966/how-come-compilers-are-so-reliable

Comment: And this quote by Linus Torvalds: "Given enough eyes, all bugs are shallow" (to paraphrase somewhat?)

Comment: Try the CTS itself first. Note that this is a user-focused site and ROM development related questions are considered off-topic here. Also, if you replace too much of the Android core, it might no longer be considered Android, and you would have to be on your own.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury From what I read, CTS is primarily for testing devices that will run Android and not for testing Android itself extensively. I think developer previews are probably for testing compatibility of developer's apps with upcoming releases; they probably won't test internal Android components. Android internals would be quite complex to perform manual checks only.

Comment: Is there a better avenue of SE where I could ask about testing Android internals? It is sufficient for me to know how various internal components of Android system are tested before being released; will clarify this in question too.

Comment: This is the right place to ask that question, but the answer is the same for any piece of open source software, unit tests, large numbers of test cases, bug reports from technical users, etc. Also, the true core of Android is Linux, and that is bugchecked separately. As it stands, I suspect not even the most experienced users here are truly qualified to answer your question. You could ask it somewhere else, but I suspect it would just get redirected here. Try your luck.

Comment: I think this should have been posted in [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com). BTW, to answer your question, all device manufacturers who don't change the AOSP code (unlike Samsung's Touchwiz) do not test the software components since they are perfectly taken care by Google.

Comment: Your question should have been like "How are internal components of Android tested **by Google** before releasing?" To answer that question, AFAIK, the testing tools are not published by Google. They do that in virtual systems. I think the other companies who change AOSP have their own minimal tools or do the major testing manually.. Someone who has better experience like playing with CyanogenMod's deep source can help better.

Comment: @GokulNC Did you mean Stack Overflow when you said Stack Exchange is probably more appropriate?

Also, I didn't know that most manufacturers make mostly minimal changes which typically don't affect internal components greatly. Thanks for that info! I will wait to see if someone does answer this for CyanogenMod.

Comment: @dnivra Yeah I meant [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)..